# anmiation freezes while playing

Tags: animation, performance

I made a short intro and it is fine, but when I press (play) the animation freezes very often. I also tried to render the animation hoping that it would run smoothly but the problem didn't get better.

Comment: So you render it out as a video and that video doesn't run smoothly on a video player too?

Comment: Can you describe better what you mean with "freezes"? Heavy scenes can reduce the viewport FPS to almost 0. Is that you case?

Comment: i rendered it as a avi raw file and tried to play it with windows media player and movie maker even while playing it in blender it freezes

Comment: well the only thing i have is a plane and text nothing special and yet the fps rate is 0.87

Comment: If you could upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ I'm sure you'll have faster answer. Could you?

Comment: also i added (quick explosion ) effect ,, might this be the cause of it?

Comment: ok .. i'll upload it

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=442" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/442/)

Comment: You also have physic enabled (collision) for each one of the 700 particles. I don't know your system spec but I think that is just a matter of calculation power. I don't see any other problem... It may take a while but it should do what is excpected. I tried to render the animation and that was fine on vlc. I'll write some suggestion in an answer.

Comment: that would be awesome,,, i'm a total noob so i'm really thankful for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scene doesn't have any particular issue. I think that on a powerful pc it would render smoothly. The freezing of the viewport is an effect of a low FPS count as your computer takes a while to calculate the position of the polygons from the simulation and render them.

The issue with the "rendered" version is probably caused by the usage of the AVI raw format that is not perfectly compatible with your video player

[image]

By exporting to another video format and waiting some time, you should obtain something like this without further adjustment.

[image]

---

Things that may affect 3D viewport performance:

- Number of polygons:

[image]

While your scene is composed by only two object, your polycount is surely considerable. You may try to reduce the resolution of the text object, expecially in the areas where the mesh is more dense.

[image]

- Simulations

You don't need to setup another level of collision (unless you are trying to achieve a particular effect) as the explode modifier is based on the particles system which have is built in phyiscs options.

[image]

- Number of particles

[image]

---

In this particular case, the more benefit cames from reducing the polycount. By roughly applying a 95% decimation modifier you can see how the preview gains about 25fps, making it usable.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow I'll try out your suggestions and thanks